# Gerund or a predicate adjective?

Tags: parts-of-speech, gerunds, predicate-adjectives

In sentences like "but now it is running" or "but now it is standing"
What are the words running/standing? I believe they're verbs/gerunds but I have some friends who think they are predicate adjectives.

What if I change the sentence to "but now it is bettering" . Is bettering an adjective here or still used as a verb?

Comment: The verb form ***to better*** is fairly uncommon, particularly as an ***intransitive*** usage. The full OED's most recent cite *(**I'm bettering** = my health is improving) is 2010, but I think it sounds positively *Victiorian*. In your cited context, ***running*** is called a (continuous) Present Participle, but that's not idiomatic for the altered version, which should be *...but now it's / it is **getting better***.

Comment: Forget using _better_ as a verb. It's so archaic nobody would know what its grammar should be. As for the POS of _running_ in _but now it is running_ depends on whether the speaker intended to characterize the watch as _a running watch_ (predicate adjective), or to characterize the action of the watch as _running now_ (present participle, part of the progressive construction -- not a gerund, btw). If you're the speaker, you know; if you're not, you get to guess. That's one reason why asking about Parts Of Speech in English is so useless.